# My iPhone will not turn on. Please give me advice

Tags: iphone

I bought and iphone 6 in December 2014. Recently it's stopped working. I put it on charge every night before bed, well last night I put it on charge and woke up and my iPhone will not turn on. I have pressed the lock and home button for atleast 30+ seconds and nothing is happening. I've tried leaving it on charge Abit more, and still nothing. It's just a black screen. I've only had my phone for nearly 8 months and I was wondering would Apple fix or replace it? I have a 12 month warranty. I am very curious and I would like some further advice.

Comment: The best advice is probably to take it to the next Apple Retail Store and talk to a genius there.

Comment: Since you've mentioned that you have a warranty, and the phone is currently still under warranty...    it seems pretty obvious that taking it in for service is the best action here?   That's the whole point of having the warranty on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

take it to the Apple Store, they'll be able to fully diagnose the issue, perhaps its a battery not holding a charge properly. If you're still under warranty(which you mentioned you are) then they will furnish you a replacement in the mean time while yours is being serviced.